# php -sql query performance

Tags: php, sql

I have a PHP SQL query that appears to be quite sluggish. We have a page that allows the user to submit a few characters and matching areas are displayed in a drop down from our SQL database. However it generally takes a few seconds to display any results from the 40 thousand entry database.

We have been wondering: is there is any way we can speed this up, or whether it could be coded more efficiently?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I believe the code is:

Our page can be seen here: http://www.movingswiftlyon.com/looking-to-buy/

Many thanks in advance

Paul

```
enter code here<?php
ini_set('memory_limit','256M');
global $wpdb;

if(!isset($wpdb))
{
require_once('../../../wp-config.php');
require_once('../../../wp-load.php');
require_once('../../../wp-includes/wp-db.php');
}

if($_GET['search']!=''){
    $query = "SELECT * FROM uk_towns2
              WHERE name LIKE '".$_GET['search']."%'";
```

Comment: Do you have any index on the `name` column?

Comment: Hi Mark, I don't believe so. How would I go about doing such and would effect any pertaining data with in row?

Comment: `ALTER TABLE uk_towns2 ADD INDEX (\`name\`)`.... and the effect it will have on existing data is to index it

Comment: Note that your query is also open to SQL injection if you have any malicious users

Comment: brilliant thanks Mark ill try figure this out :)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that "search" has no wildcards, you can speed up this query with an index on `uk_towns2(name)`.

If the name consists of multiple words, then you might consider using a full text index.  However, many names of towns in the United Kingdom are only one word, so that might not help (and I might guess that the filed `uk_towns2.name` contains the name of towns in the United Kingdom).

Another way to speed up such a search is to use n-grams.  Unfortunately, n-gram indexes are not supported in MySQL (as far as I know).  You can pre-process the data and the query, but that is rather troublesome.  Or, switch to a database such as Postgres that does support them.

Comment: Thanks for the response and sorry for my noobness but im not a coder of any degree. What is a wildcard? All we require is the a drop down of the based off the first 3 or 4 characters entered. I. E is Sels was entered onto the site Selsdon would be apart of the list provided. Also not 100% what you mean by index :s